# java 8 stream collector mapping List<List> to List

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

Lets say I have this class:

```
public class Employee{

  private int id;
  private List<Car> cars;
//getters , equals and hashcode by id
}

public class Car {
  private String name;

}
```

I have a List of Employees (same id may be duplicated):

```
List<Employee> emps =  ..

Map<Employee, List<List<Car>>> resultMap = emps.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                    Collectors.mapping(Employee::getCars, Collectors.toList());
```

This gives me `Map<Employee, List<List<Car>>>`, 
how can I get a `Map<Employee, List<Car>` (like a flat List)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see why you are using `groupingBy` when you are not doing any grouping at all. It seems all you need is to create a `Map` where the key in a `Employee` and the value is the `Employee`'s cars:

```
Map<Employee, List<Car> map =
    emps.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),Employee::getCars);
```

If you are grouping in order to join two instances of the same `Employee`, you can still use `toMap` with a merge function:

```
Map<Employee, List<Car> map =
    emps.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
                                  Employee::getCars,
                                  (v1,v2)-> {v1.addAll(v2); return v1;},
                                  HashMap::new);
```

Note that this will mutate some of the original `List`s returned by `Employee::getCars`, so you might want to create a new `List` instead of adding the elements of one list to the other.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I did not properly read the case. Your solution is fine. I was meaning to use the flatMap to convert the list of lists into a single list but as it is inside the toMap collector, your solution is way better.

Comment: Could you please help one more time? what if in Employee class we have Set<Car> cars, but I want to get Map<Employee, List<Car>>

Comment: @user1321466 In that case you can replace `Employee::getCars` with `e->new ArrayList<Car>(e.getCars())`.